# Sending Data to JSON for Database Connectivity

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, json

I have the following code which selects a data from database using web services and JSON.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    RetrievingDataFromDatabase retrievingTask;
    TextView resultView;
    String s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        retrievingTask = new RetrievingDataFromDatabase();
        retrievingTask.execute((Void) null);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void getData(){
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://PHP FILE LINK");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
        }
        //converting to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result"+ e.toString());
        }

        //parse data
        try{
            s = "";
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                s = s + json.getString("StdId").toString();
            }
            //resultView.setText(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Log_tage", "Error Parsing Data"+e.toString());
        }
    }

    class RetrievingDataFromDatabase extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            getData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            resultView.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**JSONParser.java:**

```
    public class JSONParser {
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        public JSONParser() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();           

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;

        }

}
```

**PHP File:**

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("***","***","***");

if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not Connect:' . mysql_error());
    }

mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT STID FROM database_name");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
       $output[]=$row;
    }

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

This bulk of code retrieves data from database, i need help with reversing the process ( sending data to the PHP file and selecting data depending on this value. for example:

**1-** Data received from the android application to the php file
**2-** The select from database line in the PHP file will be something like :

```
"select * from DB_name WHERE ".$valueFromAndroidApp
```

**3-** Data retrieved from database to the PHP file then the PHP sends the result to the android application.

Sorry for the long explanation, but please i need help with this.

Comment: Hi, can you describe the problem more clear? Also add code on what you have or where the problem lies. Now it seems you have one way and want to do the reverse. Not clear enough

Comment: I've edited the question, please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you a sample code for mark current location from android and send the details to the servers php file and create a new record in php.. here I have given the php file.. I assume you know how to parse json from android. if not I'll give you that also..

```
// check for required fields
 if (isset($_POST['location']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['lat']) && isset($_POST['longitude'])) {

    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];

    require_once 'config.php';
    // connecting to mysql
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    // selecting database
    mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

   // mysql inserting a new row
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO marked_locations(location, email,lat,longitude) VALUES('$location', '$email', '$lat','$longitude')");
   .....
   ..
```

location, email, lat, longitude values a come with json from android

Comment: Thanks for response @Dehan, but i have a question, the $_POST['location'] is the value that is coming from the android app ?

Comment: Sorry @Dehan, i've just seen the last line after code thanks a lot, i'll try it and hope it'll work :)